# How to do hidden filed validation Laravel?

Tags: validation, laravel-5, laravel-form

I am working in a module with Laravel and Vuejs where some fields are by default hidden. And based on user action those hidden fields are unhide and showing as form input field. These hidden fields I need to do validate when user submit the form.  Following is my Json Object for creating hidden input field:

```
"customer_order_details":{
    "payment_by": null
}
```

And Html input field in Vuejs is following:

```html
<input v-model="customer_order_details.payment_by" class ="form-control" placeholder="Payment By">
```

And validation rules in Request controller is:

```php
$rules = [
    'payment_by' => 'sometimes|required',
];
```

In the above configuration whenever I submit the form whatever `payment_by` field hide/unhide always show validation error. But I need to show validation error only when `payment_by` filed is unhidden.

Comment: Ohho, here comes html field:

<input v-model="customer_order_details.payment_by" class ="form-control" placeholder="Payment By">

Comment: I think your input is missing a name `payment_by` what is the output of `dd(request()->all());` if you put it in your controller?

Comment: No not that, it's not missing rather "payment_by" field is always there. That's why when field is hide, validation shows error.

Comment: In your example it does not have the name attribute.

Comment: it's not pure html, it's vue template.

Comment: Is `payment_by` part of an object like your json structure is ? Because then the rule should be `'customer_order_details.payment_by' => 'sometimes|required',`

Comment: @leaveme_alone are you using any vue validation package?